# Shortcode tags appear on mobile themes

Tags: shortcode, tags

I want to use a mobile theme plugin for mobile formats.  I tested five different mobile plugins and they all display my shortcode tags upon rendering on a mobile device.

The user will see the following displayed between images on their mobile device when they see my landing page:
[one_third last="no"]

[/one_third][one_third last="no"]

[/one_third][one_third last="yes"]

[/one_third]

Is there a way to suppress these tags so they don't display? Is there a free mobile plugin that does not have this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: If your problem is specific to some plugin, you should ask to the plugin developer, we don't know how it works. [See the topics should be asked here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Plugins recommendations are also off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile theme plugins typically sniff the user agent and just switch out your main theme for a bundled "mobile friendly" generic one. In the process, any shortcodes registered in your theme are no longer recognised, and they just display as plain text.

Check out the plugin documentation, or contact the developer, and see if they can offer any insight. I would also check out the source of the plugin and see what actions/hooks are available - there will (almost) always be some way of "injecting" your original theme's functionality back into the plugin theme.